# Motorized Blinds - No Remote, Can't Find The Manufactuer

Tags: windows, electric-motor

When I moved here, there were motorized blackout blinds everywhere. They were awesome.
I lost the remote.
I didn't buy them; I can't find the manufacturer. I took too good guesses, and neither remote works.
I played with them so much that they won't even open and close manually.
How do I figure out how to get them working and buy the CORRECT remote?

They are expensive. I would hate to have to replace them.

Comment: Can't find the manufacturer or can't find a label/stamp with their name?

Comment: Can take a picture of the blinds to a local window/blind shop.  They might know the maker or how to get a remote.

Comment: the remote typically matches the motor.  the motors almost always have stickers or some model number so you can replace when they die.  pictures are helpful.

Comment: Great ideas... I will take it apart and see what I find.

Comment: I took one of the apart but didn't find anything. I took photos but don't know how to attach them.